# input type="date" is not supported in Internet Explorer for an Angular project

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I'm trying to implement a datePicker in my Angular project. The datepicker works well on Chrome and Microsoft Edge but it doesn't work on Internet Explorer, it's not supported.
Is there any programmatic solution or a library can solve the problem?

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="dateInputt" class="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2011-08-19" id="dateInput" formControlName="dateInput">
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: You can use a date picker component library and write code to swap `type="date"` with `type="text"` for IE.

Comment: Hello @HereticMonkey, thank you for response, can you be more specific ? thank you

Comment: Read the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: actually it dosen't solve the problem with angular projects! thank you anyway

Comment: There are 14 answers to that duplicate question, but if you find that none of them work with your configuration, feel free to [edit] your question to explain this and your question will go into a reopen queue.